# performSelector not working in unit test Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, unit-testing

I am trying to make a unit test for my application but performSelector doesn't work.
I've tried

`[self performSelector:@selector(checkIDs:) withObject:nil];`

and performSelectorOnMainThread but for some reason the method doesn't get called.

```
 [self checkIDs:nil]
```

seems to work fine but performSelector doesn't. Getting this method to get called is not my main concern. The reason for me asking is because I have a bigger problem but I think the reason is because performSelector isn't working.

Am I missing something? Once again, this is for a Unit Test. Thanks!

Comment: Does checkIDS: take an object of type id and does it return an object of type id? If not to either part of the question, use NSInvocation instead.

Comment: The checkIDS function doesn't return an id it's a void function, but I need to know whyit's not working. I am importing header files that use performSelector so I'm wondering if these classes are affected in a unit test environment. The apple docs on performSelector says that it should work, no idea why it wouldn't call the method.

Comment: Check your code. Have you defined it as - (void)checkIDs; or - (void)checkIDs:(id)someObject; ? In the first case you need to use @selector(checkIDs), in the second case @selector(checkIDs:). performSelector does work in unit tests, I just used it myself in a SenTestCase.

Comment: Could you please provide some more code, some context? From what you posted, it's hard to guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self checkIDs:nil];
});
```

Try this it should work.